# AES/Rijndael implementation for SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server-2000, aes, rijndael

Do you know any function implementation I could use for decrypting data encrypted by AES/Rijndael in SQL Server 2000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[xp_crypt](http://www.xpcrypt.com/products.html) might do it

Without the CLR and other whizzy stuff in SQL Server 2005+ it will be difficult in the raw SQL available in SQL Server 2000.